# Embed Facebook video via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

I have a Database where I store the ID of X videos from Facebook also, Youtube and vimeo, then I load any video via Ajax, vimeo and Youtube load perfectly but Facebook doesn't load, it only loads the html but the code that I get via ajax also contains a script wich is requiered by Facebook...
To embed a video from Facebook the code is this:

```
<script>
    (function(d, s, id)
    {  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')
        );
</script>
<div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm visible-md visible-lg">
    <div id="fbid">
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <div class="fb-post" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=<?php echo $v->v; ?>" data-width="800">
            <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with this code I can embed facebook videos, if I go directly to my ajax file, http://foo.com/ajax.php?i=1 it will output that code only for facebook and that is what I get and it display the video correctly, but if I call it using ajax I only see the html but the script doesn't get executed in other words I don't see the video... 
My ajax is this

```
$('.v_list li').click(function(){
    var $ids = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: "v.php",
        data: {
            vid: $ids
        },
        type: "GET",
        // dataType: "html", // test #7 .. working for all
        context: document.body, // change #8
        success: function (data) {
            $("#slider").html(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert("Ocurrio un problema!");
        },
        complete: function (xhr, data) {
            // hide the loading img
        }
    }).done (function (data) {
        // alert('sss'); // This is working...
        $("#slider").find("script").each(function(i) {
            eval($(this).text());
        }); // this p*** of s*** is not working... 
    });
})
```

So the only problem I got is when the video is for Facebook... how can I solve this?... thanks

Comment: @luschn has the right answer. why didn't accept that as correct!?

Comment: @denns, maybe because I forgot about this question and I ended using a different method for that project, but yes, luschn is correct, so I just marked as the right answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After loading the HTML code with AJAX, you may need to use FB.XFBML.parse:

```
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse